# Drop set of columns with only null values from a table using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot-table, temp-tables

Take for example this example as an illustration so you can see what Î'm trying to do.

This is how the final table of the pivoted information looks like.

```
Create Table [#Comparative]
(
    Branch char(32),
    [2004_January] numeric (18,2),
    [2005_January] numeric (18,2),
    [2006_January] numeric (18,2),
    [2007_January] numeric (18,2),
    [2008_January] numeric (18,2),
)


INSERT INTO [#Comparative]
VALUES ('Angeles', NULL, 13550.20, 7820.50, NULL, NULL),
       ('Detroit', NULL, 13550.20, 7820.50, NULL, NULL),
       ('New York', NULL, 13550.20, 7820.50, NULL, NULL),
       ('Arizona', NULL, 13550.20, 7820.50, NULL, NULL)

Select * from [#Comparative]
```

How could i create a procedure or statement
to drop the set of columns that contains only NULL values taking 
into account the columns on the table will be changing as the table is created from other 
query that takes information of daily sales to group sum(sales) monthly depending
on the interval of the selected date.

Comment: please provide good question detail this is quite confusing,

Comment: i corrected the question detail thank you.

Comment: this is wrong , you cant delete set of column with base on some condition . you can drop column .

Comment: sorry i corrected the term delete for drop, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically create a SQL statement and then run that command. This script drop set of columns with only null values from a temporary table(passed as parameter in SP).

```
CREATE PROC dbo.dropColumn
@tempTableName nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @dml nvarchar(max) = N''
  SELECT @dml += 'IF (SELECT MIN(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') FROM [dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@tempTableName) + ') IS NULL' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                 'BEGIN' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                 '  EXEC (''ALTER TABLE [dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@tempTableName) + ' DROP COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ''')' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                 'END' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
  FROM tempdb.sys.tables t JOIN tempdb.sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
  WHERE t.object_id = OBJECT_ID('[tempdb].[dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@tempTableName))
  --PRINT @dml

  EXEC sp_executesql @dml
END

EXEC dbo.dropColumn '#Comparative'
```

Result:

```
Branch                              2005_January    2006_January
----------------------------------------------------------------
Angeles                             13550.20        7820.50
Detroit                             13550.20        7820.50
New York                            13550.20        7820.50
Arizona                             13550.20        7820.50
```

Comment: That was a correct proccedure for this case.  TY :) that was a very helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this : this is one example.

CREATE Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestSP
(
    @IsDroped BIT       
)AS
BEGIN

    declare @test int
    declare @testcount int
    set @testcount = (select COUNT(*) from mtp )

    set @test = (select distinct 1 from mtp where name is null  group by name having COUNT(*)=@testcount  )

    if @test = 1 AND @IsDroped = 1
    begin
    alter table mtp drop column name
    end

END
```

Execute this SP

```
EXEC TestSP 1
```

Comment: Ty it looks a good answer, but how can i do it if i have multiple columns like my example.

Comment: create one Stored procedure and perform this block .

Comment: i'll try using your example ty

Comment: could you help me giving me an example of the stored proccedure

Comment: i see, ty for the reply but i dont see a way to do it that way because the column name is dynamic or maybe i'm missing something.  thanks.